# Make LEAST() function return a non-empty value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have 5 columns with dates (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5), some of them are empty or with null.
I need to find a min Date from all of these columns.

I'm using "least" function, its work fine, but if I have one column with date and others columns are empty, the "least" will return to me empty field !

How to skip the empty fields or null columns, and return only dates! Or i need to check every column is empty or not before using least function ! 
Thanks !

```
select id, least(vi_date1, vi_date2,vi_date3,vi_date4,vi_date5) as "Min Date", vi_date1, vi_date2,vi_date3,vi_date4,vi_date5 from table
```

Comment: `LEAST` can't be used directly to tables with `NULL` values..Because `LEAST` returns `NULL` when a columns value is `NULL`

Comment: Ok, I see, what about empty columns !?? I can replace all null to empty !

Comment: I would convert the empty and NULL values into date format `9999-12-31`, Something like `IF(vi_date1 = '' OR vi_date1 IS NULL, '9999-12-31', vi_date1)`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my task is to find max and min in all 5 dates columns, for max result, it will not work !

Comment: Define "empty". Are those date/datetime columns or varchars?

Comment: these columns are text!

Comment: "Thanks for answer, but my task is to find max and min in all 5 dates columns, for max result, it will not work ! " Using LEAST also will not work for the max value. You max you need to use GREATEST..

Comment: @Ktp uh oh. Are the dates stored like dates (fixed width, ymd format) or like `It was a beautiful evening of Wednesday, 31st of October, 1963`

Comment: @SalmanA '2018-06-05'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `IF(col <> '', col, '...')` to convert NULL and empty strings to a large (or small) value, then use LEAST (or GREATEST) function:

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(LEAST(
        IF(vi_date1 <> '', vi_date1, '9999-12-31'),
        IF(vi_date2 <> '', vi_date2, '9999-12-31'),
        IF(vi_date3 <> '', vi_date3, '9999-12-31'),
        IF(vi_date4 <> '', vi_date4, '9999-12-31'),
        IF(vi_date5 <> '', vi_date5, '9999-12-31')
    ),'9999-12-31') AS Min_Date,
    NULLIF(GREATEST(
        IF(vi_date1 <> '', vi_date1, '1000-01-01'),
        IF(vi_date2 <> '', vi_date2, '1000-01-01'),
        IF(vi_date3 <> '', vi_date3, '1000-01-01'),
        IF(vi_date4 <> '', vi_date4, '1000-01-01'),
        IF(vi_date5 <> '', vi_date5, '1000-01-01')
    ),'1000-01-01') AS Max_Date,
    vi_date1,
    vi_date2,
    vi_date3,
    vi_date4,
    vi_date5
FROM testdata
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qXBKz5WTFdpF6nevsFXSb9/0)

Comment: for some reason this didnt work, but when I removed the `NULLIF` and `,'1000-01-01')` it worked. any way to also set the condition if its null OR if greater than `now`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COALESCE` function to ignore `NULL` values

**Update - Include min and max date - Also check the null or empty dates**

```
  select Id, least(COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date1,''), '9999-12-31 23:59:59') , 
                   COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date2,''),'9999-12-31 23:59:59'),
                   COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date3,''),'9999-12-31 23:59:59'),
                   COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date4,''),'9999-12-31 23:59:59'),
                   COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date5,''),'9999-12-31 23:59:59')) as "Min Date", 
          , GREATEST(COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date1,''), '1000-01-01 00:00:00') , 
                   COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date2,''),'1000-01-01 00:00:00'),
                   COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date3,''),'1000-01-01 00:00:00'),
                   COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date4,''),'1000-01-01 00:00:00'),
                   COALESCE(IFNULL(vi_date5,''),'1000-01-01 00:00:00')) as "Max Date", 
          vi_date1, vi_date2,vi_date3,vi_date4,vi_date5 
          vi_date1, vi_date2,vi_date3,vi_date4,vi_date5 
 from table
```

Comment: Wrong function nesting.. LEAST would still return the NULL value first..

Comment: This also does not work COALESCE will return the first non NULL value meaning one value goes into the LEAST function.

Comment: I don't know but this solution doesn't work for me ! This query return to me only rows which have all 5 columns with dates.